# "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" for assets, css, app.js and vendor.js in production (react, babel, webpack)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am setting up a copy of steemit cllient from https://github.com/steemit/steemit.com.

everything works in development environment but when I try to run same in production following steps provided in github repo, it gives error in console : "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" [image: (screenshot attached)]

I am unable to relate this issue to anything.  I am relatively new to webpack. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: OK, what i found so far is https is causing "net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED". 
So any input on making https work on local or changing https to http in configuration ?

Answer (score 1):

fixed it by removing "content="upgrade-insecure-requests" from server-html.jsx so that i can test production on local. it's useful for production. if anyone wants to look into it, i found details here: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/csp-upgrade-insecure-requests/